# how to convert a character into a character array in C

Tags: c, stack, prefix, infix-notation

I wrote a program to convert prefix to infix in C using stacks but I am not able to convert the character in the prefix expression into an array. for push()function. The stack has an array pointer to a string and hence for push function i must convert the character into character array . I tried to write `char arrtemp={array[i]}` but on printing the value of `arrtemp` I am getting some random characters. Someone please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 100
struct stack
{
    int top;
    char *arr[100];
    int size;
};

struct stack *createstack(int size)
{
    struct stack *stack;
    stack = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    if (!stack)
        return NULL;
    stack->size = size;
    stack->top = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        stack->arr[i] = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    return stack;
}

int isEmpty(struct stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->top == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void pop(struct stack *stack)
{
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        stack->top--;
}

void push(char value[], struct stack *stack)
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr=value;
    stack->top++;
   printf("%s ",value);
    strcpy(stack->arr[stack->top],ptr);
}
char *ptr;
char *peek(struct stack *stack)
{
ptr=stack->arr[stack->top];
    return ptr;
} 
int oper(char ch)
{
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void in_post(char array[], int len)
{
    int i_new = 0;
    // static char infix[300];
    struct stack *stacks;
    i_new = 0;
    stacks = createstack(len);
    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {char arrtemp[]={array[i]};
   // printf("%s ",arrtemp);
        if (oper(array[i]) == 0)
        { //  printf("%s \n ",array[i]);
            push(array[i], stacks);
            //printf("%s ",stacks->arr[stacks->top]);
        }
        else if (oper(array[i] != 0))
        {   char *ch2,*ch1;
            strcpy(ch1, peek(stacks));
            printf("%s ",peek(stacks));
            pop(stacks);

            strcpy(ch2, peek(stacks));
            pop(stacks);
            char temp[] = {'('};
            char close[]={')'};
            strcat(temp,ch1);
            strcat(temp,arrtemp);
            strcat(temp,ch2);
            strcat(temp,close);
            push(temp, stacks);
        }
    }
    printf("%s ",peek(stacks));
}
int main()
{
    char xprsn[300];
    printf("Enter the expression :\n");
    scanf("%s", &xprsn);
    //printf("%d ",strlen(xprsn));
     in_post(xprsn,strlen(xprsn));
}
```

Comment: Note: you can’t define `temp` as a single byte array and then use `strcat` to append to it. Also using `sprintf` would be much more useful than `strcat` multiple times.

Comment: but what about arrtemp, I am getting some random characters when I try to print arrtemp.

Comment: That’s because you are printing it as a null terminated string without it being null terminated